# CSS Shapes and border

Tags: css

I didn't undestand this css in this http://jsfiddle.net/b45aX/

```
   border-top: 13px solid transparent;
   border-right: 26px solid purple;
   border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
```

How they can make this shape like arrow ?

Comment: i want understand how not just have a code.

Comment: surely if you look at how the different options effect the css you are then brainey enough to figure out how it works?  If not my mistake